# Unable to Install Laravel 4.1 on Maverics OS X

Tags: laravel, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install laravel 4.1 on Maverics OS X using the document provided on the laravel site.

I am trying only two methods provided: via laravel installer & via composer. The third option is not preferred because I will only be able to apply these two methods on my production server.

I get following errors

a) Using via laravel Installer: I issue following commands (assuming I have downloaded in downloads dir)

```
downloads$ mv laravel.phar /usr/local/bin
cd ~/rohinigeeks
rohinigeeks$ sudo laravel rohinigeeks
```

ERROR:

```
sudo: laravel: command not found
```

---

b) Using Via Composer. I issue following commands

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel rohinigeeks --prefer-dist
```

ERROR:

```
[ErrorException]                                                             
unlink(/Users/apple/.composer/cache/files/symfony/security/ef511d47c94ad92e  
37112b43efcbf7da8696a803.zip): Permission denied
```

Your help will be appreciated.

-AK

Answer (score 0):

You installed `laravel.phar` in `/usr/local/bin`, so use that as the command name. Or rename it to `/usr/local/bin/laravel`:

```
mv laravel.phar /usr/local/bin/laravel
```

Also make sure it's executable:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/laravel
```

And if you're using `tcsh` (is this still the OSX default?), make sure to use `rehash`.